# Class-validator: How accept missing field?

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

The validator throw error "brandId must be a number conforming to the specified constraints",
when I missing "not require" field in body.

My validator class:

```
export class CreateNotificationDto {
  @IsNumber()
  userId: number

  @IsNumber()
  brandId: number

  @IsNumber()
  companyId: number

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @MinLength(1)
  @MaxLength(255)
  title: string

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @MinLength(1)
  @MaxLength(50)
  type: string

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  message: string 
}
```

my controller:

```
 @Post()
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard)
  @UseInterceptors(Interceptor)
  async create(@Body() dto: CreateNotificationDto, @TransactionParam() transaction: Transaction): Promise<Notification> {
    const room = `room-user-${dto.userId}`

    const data = await this.notificationService.create(dto, transaction)

    await this.notificationGateWay.sendNoti({
      room,
      message: data.message
    })

    return data
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@IsOptional()` decorator. For optional fields.

Comment: tks u, it work!